# What's the best way to find a car in Player Unknown's Battlegrounds?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

I like playing the outer edges of the map, but sometimes the first circle is all the way on the other side and I end up pretty much guaranteed to die unless I can find a car.

And I'm really, really bad at finding a car.

What kinds of places do they spawn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done a bit more looking around and found [this thread on the forum](http://forums.playbattlegrounds.com/topic/1439-vehicles-typical-location-random-or-strict-or/). It has a quote from a moderator so not sure how accurate that is, though it does seem to fall inline with what I've seen:

> From my experience the locations are 100% pre-set, but each spot only has a certain chance to spawn the car each game.
>   You're almost always guaranteed to find a car near the coast on the side of a road.
>   Other than that, like you said garages are a good place to find them.. and towns in general.

After some further research I found this map on [steam](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=892081950) that is a work in progress of garage locations that spawn cars:

[image: Garage map]

---

The next part of the answer is based off of my own experiences.

**Disclaimer**: I have no official sources on this and it's all based on my own experiences playing the game.

I usually find the best way to find a car is to follow a main road or look near a main road. Usually also looking near buildings/houses and I can find one. This is only purely speculative and based on what I've seen so far.

I have also found a car inside a garage that is attached to a building but only rarely.

---

I just managed to get into game for a bit and I've noticed that the UAZ seems to spawn in fields near buildings usually the more industrial ones. Something else to look out for.

---

However, as I usually land middle map-ish on an isolated set of buildings I try to run everywhere. This also has the advantages of:

- Not landing near so many players
- Not being so loud as you move so it's harder for others to detect you

But it does have the disadvantage of not starting out with much stuff, or as good stuff, as you usually would have unless you get luck.

Comment: If I get time later I will add locations I've seen a car spawn in not in a garage,

Comment: Nice improvements to this answer. Overall, though, I've mostly given up and now I just parachute to a few specific coast areas because they almost always have a boat. :P

Comment: @Sterno Yeah :) I either do that or land at some small group of buildings and hope they have a gun! There isn't really any other information at the moment though. Pretty much look near a main road or a garage seems to be the best advice so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check this map which will tell you what vehicle spawns are more likely,
and what spawns are more luck-based.

[image: Clean map]
[image: Precise map]

Comment: One thing to note, this map will probably not be accurate come the new patch on May 25th 2017. The 100% vehicle spawns is supposedly a bug that will be patched.  [Patch notes here](http://steamcommunity.com/games/578080/announcements/detail/1271550628459839077)

Comment: Still the locations will be true, just replace `100% Vehicule` by : `Very high vehicle spawn rate`

Comment: The locations may be true, but the difference between "100% spawn rate" and "High Spawn rate", could be the difference between dying to the blue circle and a chicken dinner. :)